# Redirect emails to default email address for testing purpose

Tags: moqui

I am working on email feature in moqui. I am able to configure the EmailServer data and  email feature working fine. I would like to know that do we have any way in moqui to redirect all email to an specific address for testing purpose. Like we have "mail.notification.redirectTo" feature in OFBiz?

I am not able to find this kind of feature in moqui. How can we achieve this functionality?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not currently a setting like this. The main debug approaches I use are leaving the default EmailServer record as-is so that email sending is disabled and the message text is logged and setting email addresses to one of my own email addresses. Setting my own email address on the john.doe account is easy because I leave my test settings including email server details (un, pw, url, etc) in a data load file that I load when testing things that require this sort of configuration.